# How use relational operators with number generics?

Tags: java

How can I use relational operators with Java number generics?

```
 public class Test<K extends Number>{

 private K key;

 public boolean f (int i){
     return i < key;    //ERROR
 }

 public boolean g (K k){
     return k < key;    //ERROR
 }
}
```

Is there any solution for it? compareTo?

Comment: There is no solution. What would be the result of `i < key` if `key` was an object of my custom subclass of `Number` that you knew nothing about?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: Number is not Comparable.

Comment: @BheshGurung oh, you're right. Wel, you still have `intValue` and similar methods to retrieve the stored value and use it for comparisons. Do your design depending on your needs.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis what about `i < key.intValue()`? Or even wiser, change `K` to also implement `Comparable`: `<K extends Number, Comparable<K>>`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: But how would you know that it's going to be Integer and not something else.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Probably. OP should clarify what the comparison should be.

Comment: @BheshGurung that will depend on your design. If you have a `Short`, then you can only return the current value as `int`. If you have a `Long`, you can define to return `Integer.MAX_VALUE` to avoid overflow...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution would be marking `K` to extend `Number` and implement `Comparable<K>`:

```
public class Test<K extends Number & Comparable<K>>{

    private K key;

    public boolean f (int i) {
        if (!(key instanceof Integer)) {
            return false;
        }
        return new Integer(i).compareTo((Integer)key) < 0;
    }

    public boolean g (K k){
        return k.compareTo(key) < 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.1) states

> The type of each of the operands of a numerical comparison operator
>   **must be a type that is convertible (§5.1.8) to a primitive numeric
>   type**, or a compile-time error occurs.

and

> A type is said to be **convertible to a numeric type** if it is a
>   numeric type (§4.2), or it is a **reference type that may be converted
>   to a numeric type by unboxing conversion.**

These [reference types are](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8)

> From type `Boolean` to type `boolean`
>
> From type `Byte` to type `byte`
>
> From type `Short` to type `short`
>
> From type `Character` to type `char`
>
> From type `Integer` to type `int`
>
> From type `Long` to type `long`
>
> From type Float to type float
>
> From type `Double` to type `double`

Since all you know about `K` is that it is a subclass of `Number` and therefore not guaranteed to be any of the above, you cannot use a reference of type `K` as an operand of the `<` operator.

You would have to devise a strategy with the `Comparable` interface depending on what you are trying to achieve and how types should be compared.