# Trying to learn generics, is there a way to see if one generic object is bigger or smaller then another?

Tags: java, generics

I thought it would be nice to use generics to write a quick sort.  I'm just learning generics, and it seems like you can only test whether one generic value is equal to another.  Is there a way to see if one is greater then another?  I wrote a simple isBig method as follows

```
public Boolean  isBigger( T b)
{
        if (b>x) // error message here
            return true;

        return false;
}
```

Comment: What if `T` will be used to represent non metric type like Boolean? How `b1>b2` should be evaluated? Or maybe lets use `Color`, how `color1>color2` should be calculated?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22873748/how-use-relational-operators-with-number-generics and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26447035/compile-error-when-implement-a-simple-generic-function-in-java

Comment: `>` can not be applied to arbitrary objects; use `compareTo`.

Comment: @Pshemo `Boolean.compareTo` has known semantics.

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes, it has *some* default semantics which uses assumption that `true>false` but it looks more Java creators assumed that since we will want to order our POJOs on some boolean value stored by them it would be good to implement some default order so they chose `true>false`. They could also chose `true<false` and nothing bad would happen. My point is that some instances can't be easily determined if they are bigger than others so compiler can't know what `a<b` should be compiled into (what predefined set of operations should be executed to evaluate it) for any `T`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>>
boolean isBigger(T x, T y) {
  return x != null && (y == null || x.compareTo(y) > 0);
}

public static <T>
boolean isBigger(T x, T y, Comparator<? super T> cmp) {
  return cmp.compare(x, y) > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually, generics are wrong for this purpose. Instead you should have a look at the interfaces `Comparable` and `Comparator` - Using these is the way to implement a generic sorting algorithm (as `java.util.Collections` does)

Answer (score 4):

You can't use a greater than operator on a generic type parameter, since that operator is only defined for primitives.

You can use methods such as `compare` or `compareTo` if your generic type parameter is bound by an interface that contains that method (such as `Comparable`).

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare by an object's field that you consider relevant to the comparison. For sorting through a list of objects by one field you can use Comparator.

[How to use Comparator in Java to sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839137/how-to-use-comparator-in-java-to-sort)

Comment: Side note: 3 somewhat equivalent answers delivered at the same time :)